# Modal shows previous data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I have a little "bug" here. I have a modal that receives a text, that corresponds a message to show, a state and a property to restore the values of the states when the modal close. In the main, I have three states, each one represents different situations and each show a unique message. The problem occurs when I run the app, choose a date in a datetimepicker, evaluate that in a function, and then I sent that result in a conditional, if "result" is in a determined range -> I set a specific state, else, set another state. Once a state is true, the modal opens with the specific text.

The problem take place when the modal open, the information correspond to a previous "result". I tried to debug with console logs, and I saw that the states doesn't update.

Is it possible that the states take a time to update? Or could be a problem with the cache of the device?

I attach the code below.

Here are the definition of the states

```
const [modalVisible1, setModalVisible1] = useState(false)

const [modalVisible2, setModalVisible2] = useState(false)

const [modalVisible3, setModalVisible3] = useState(false)
```

This is the conditional that I explained. `picker_value` is a variable that take an option from a menu by the user.

```
const setModal = () => {
    (picker_value ===2 && (result>6 && result<150)) ? setModalVisible1(true) : setModalVisible2(true)
    if(picker_value == 3)
        setModalVisible3(true)
}
```

And finally, I have this expression (one for each state), to show the modal with the respective message

```
{modalVisible1 && <MyModal
                    message={"Test123"}
                    state={modalVisible1}
                    restore={resetModal}
                    />
                }
```

And I detach the modal

```
export const MyModal = (props) => {
return (
  <Modal visible={props.state}
        transparent={true}
        animationType='slide'
        >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{props.message}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.restore()}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  </Modal>
);
```

EDIT: onChange Method. Date is the current day, and days is a state that saves the result from process_days (calculates the diff between 2 dates)

```
const [days, setDays] = useState(0)

   const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios')
    setSelectedDay(selectedDate)
    setDays(process_days(date, selectedDate))
    setPickerValue(formData.pickerValue)
    setModal()
}
```

Reset states

```
    const resetModal = () => {
    setModalVisible1(false)
    //same for each modal
}
```

Comment: more information is needed, especially the part where u change value.

Comment: I edit the post! Thanks for reply!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example